# CSS bottom alignment with floated div

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have a problem about bottom alignment of a div and I don't find any solutions.

All div are contained in a main div, one is left floated and all other must be place on the right of it;
Just one of them it must be bottom aligned, but trying with position absolute and bottom tag it's placed over the floated one.

CSS:

```
#container {width:730px;position: relative;min-height:120px;}
#image_box    {width:220px; float:left; padding-right:10px;background:#222;color:#FFF;}
#box_dx1   {width:500px;background:#666;}
#box_dx2   {width:500px;padding-top:10px;background:#999;}
#box_dx3   {width:500px;padding-top:10px;background:#CCC;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="image_box">Box Sx Image <br>Row<br>Row<br>Row<br>Row<br>Row<br>Row</div>
  <div id="box_dx1">Box Dx Title</div>
  <div id="box_dx2">Box Dx Description</div>
  <div id="box_dx3">Box Dx Param</div>
</div>
```

Moreover div's heights are variable, image_box is optional(cannot exist) and text of box_dx2 could wrap under the image_box.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Does `position:absolute;bottom:0;` do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the height of `box_dx1`, `box_dx3` and `image-box` is always going to be same, you could just set a `min-height` for `box_dx2`. That way, if you add more content to `box_dx2` it will eventually become taller than the image and text will wrap around it. In your example it would be something like:

```
#box_dx2 { 
    width: 500px; 
    padding-top:10px; 
    background:#999; 
    min-height: 70px; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/Lb8X6/)

However, if the height of those boxes isn't fixed, maybe the easist thing is to calculate the `min-height` using some jQuery.